# inputStream encoding issues (Special characters: ñ, á,...)

Tags: java, web-services, utf-8, http-post, inputstream

Welcome all, I'm currently working on a web-service and I'm having a lot of trouble to make this method work with characters like ñ, ç, á, è,... It's seems to be related with my Input stream, it doesn't seem to be encoding properly, here's the code:

```
    private static String sendPost(String url, Map<String, JSONObject> params) throws Exception {
    String responseString;

    StringBuilder urlParameters = new StringBuilder(400);
    if (params != null) {
        for (Entry<String, JSONObject> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            urlParameters.append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue().toString()).append("&");
        }

    }
    url += urlParameters.toString();
    url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        StringBuffer response = null;
        try{
            //when i check 'con' all seems to be fine
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
        }finally{
            in.close();
        }
        responseString = response.toString();
    } else {
        responseString = new StringBuilder(25).append(responseCode).toString();
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

Example:
Inside "con" http:\direction.dom\data\W-S\something?param={example:"castaña"}
and InputStream returns: http:\direction.dom\data\W-S\something?param={example:"casta�a"}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "InputStream returns"? Do you get broken characters in `responseString`? If so, how do you determine that the String is broken (as opposed to whatever you use to look at the String, such as a log file output)?

Comment: Or are the special characters in the *request* URL? Those probably need to be encoded.

Comment: So what encoding is used by the webservice to write to the data stream? If you don't know, try "Cp1252". This is windows-1252 often used as a default in Windows for western countries. Otherwise you can try to write the raw bytes from the input stream to a file and try to open it with a text editor, hoping the editor can guess the encoding.

Comment: Thanks for asking, I was talking about the `in.readLine()`. When I did debug I check the data inside `con` and the params of the mehod and all seems to be fine but when I do `inputLine = in.readLine()` it places broken chars inside `inputLine`. @vanje if I don't do this `new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")` I get the data in `cp1252` so I guess `cp1252` is the default encoding.

Comment: When you create your InputStreamReader, replace "UTF-8" with `new MimeType(con.getContentType()).getParameter("charset")`.  That way, you’ll always be using the correct charset instead of blindly assuming UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My partner just figure how to solve it:

```
private static String sendPost(String url, Map<String, JSONObject> params) throws Exception {
    String responseString;

    StringBuilder urlParameters = new StringBuilder(400);
    if (params != null) {
        for (Entry<String, JSONObject> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            urlParameters.append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue().toString()).append("&");
        }
    }

    url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", "UTF-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(wr, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(urlParameters.toString());
    writer.close();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        StringBuffer response = null;
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
        }finally{
            in.close();
        }
        responseString = response.toString();
    } else {
        responseString = new StringBuilder(25).append(responseCode).toString();
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really tricky case because you're dealing with HTTP params. Those can be in any encoding that the user enters in your browser.

Based on your example, your user sends his data in something other than `UTF-8`. It can be `ISO-8859-1`, `ISO-8859-15` or `windows-1252`.

You can make push your users towards UTF-8 by setting the right HTTP header to your web form: `response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=utf-8)`:

Comment: Isn't the code shown the "user" (i.e. the one making the request)?

Comment: For development, yes. Once it goes to production, end-users won't have access to this code.